# Batch Script in Windows 10 to Rename IES Files

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script to rename a couple of .IES-Files in a folder.
My knowledge is very low on this i cannot figure out why is it not renaming.

I expect that the script is renaming but it won´t do that. I do not know why. May somebody can take a look at it to help me.

```
@echo off

:input
set /p root_directory=Enter the path to the root directory:

if not exist "%root_directory%" goto input

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%root_directory%\*.ies"') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%l in ('type "%%f"') do (
        if "%%l" == "[LUMINAIRE]" (
            set "new_name=%%l"
            set "new_name=!new_name:~12!"
            set "new_name=!new_name: =!"
            set "new_name=!new_name:~1,-1!"
            set "new_name=!new_name!.ies"
            if not exist "%%~dpf%new_name%" ren "%%f" "%new_name%"
        )
    )
)

echo Done!
pause
```

Comment: What are all of those `set` commands for? It appears that all you are doing is renaming the first `.ies` file in each subdirectory not already containing a file named `LUMINAIRE.ies` if it contains the line `[LUMINAIRE]` to `LUMINAIRE.ies`. Why can you not use `findstr.exe`? Please open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key to learn how to use it.

Comment: Please post some examples of what you want to do. As it stands, you are looking in each `.ies` file and attempting to find a line `[LUMINAIRE]` in that file. if `[LUMINAIRE]` is found, then attempt a rename, but what file gets renamed and what you want to make its new name are unclear.